# Customization the Header Text of a WooCommerce Email Notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am customizing the email notification a customer receives when a partial refund or refund is processed through WooCommerce. I have copied the template over into the child theme and made the content modifications needed in the body of the email. However, I would like to change the words "Partial Refund" in the header of the email to "Your Refund Information" for both partial refunds and full refunds. I have copied over the email-header.php file into the child theme's WooCommerce directory (and then subdirectory). I think this is the code I would have to change.

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
        <title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ); ?></title>
    </head>
```

I would imagine I have to change the bloginfo part to an echo (not a techie here but trying here). I feel I'm close but don't know how to modify the echo! If anyone can help, I would appreciate it! TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a case of not being able to see straight after working an issue for so long. WooCommerce gives you the capability of changing both the subject and the header of the email notification under the "manage" settings tab. I was so intent on changing the code to fix the problem, I did not see that it was a function within Woo. I apologize but wanted to post the resolution here in case it will help someone else. (I actually hired someone to show me the quick fix!)